# What is the difference between community and non-community answers on a given SE?

Tags: discussion, questions, community

I have answered I believe around 12 questions on Chess Stack Exchange with > 1 for all of them. How come I only have credit for 3 in terms of non-community answers? What is the difference between a community and non-community question?

Comment: What do you mean by credit? I see 13 answers on your Chess SE profile.

Comment: @animuson There is a bar that says that I need 20 non-community questions or something like that

Comment: Are you referring to the "next tag badge" section of your profile? That's showing you your progress towards the 'strategy' bronze tag badge, for which you need 20 non-CW answers *to questions tagged 'strategy'*. You currently have 3.

Comment: @ff524 Yes. I am wondering why I shouldn't have 12 or something like that.

Comment: Because you have only answered 3 questions tagged 'strategy'?